# How to compile Android App on api level 8 (Android 2.2) using Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, sdk, android-2.2-froyo

The title of my question is more clear than I can explain here..
What I need for some reasons is to get the way to compile some Android apps, using the Api level 8 for Android 2.2.
Unfortunately some of my customers have this kind of version installed.
I tried to create a New SDK on XE7 but I can only use api level 19!

Comment: This is why you should use the native development tooling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi does not support Android 2.2. The minimum API Level supported is 10, per the documentation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development